# Ubuntu Python give full permission to tree

Tags: python, ubuntu, chmod

I want to give full permission to a directory and its content in Ubuntu using python. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228296/permission-change-of-files-in-python) using `os.walk`:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
     for filename in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        os.chmod(path, 0o777) # for example
```

But I wonder if there isn't a more simple/elegant solution?

Comment: Take a look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187200/chmod-recursively-directories-only

Comment: From @AhsanulHaque linked question, I recommend you do something like `[os.chmod(r, 0777) for r,d,f in os.walk(path)]`.

Comment: Thanks! that works: for python 3 I use `0o777`

Answer (score 0):

using subprocess module:
call("chmod -R 777 "+folder)